# How to set a maximum no. for a Coupon can be used in Django Project

Tags: python, django

I have set a Coupon Payment System for my E-commerce project but I want to set a maximum no. of usage for this coupon for maximum 10 times.

How do I do that?

Here is the models.py

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    valid_to = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

Here is the views.py

```
class AddCouponView(View):
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        now = timezone.now()
        form = CouponForm(self.request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                code = form.cleaned_data.get('code')
                order = Order.objects.get(
                    user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
                coupon_qs = Coupon.objects.filter(code__iexact=code, valid_from__lte=now,
                                                  valid_to__gte=now,active=True)
                order_coupon = Order.objects.filter(coupon=coupon_qs.first(), user=self.request.user)

                if order_coupon:
                    messages.error(self.request, "You can't use same coupon again")
                    return redirect('core:checkout')
                if coupon_qs:
                    order.coupon = coupon_qs[0]
                    order.save()
                    messages.success(self.request, "Successfully added coupon")
                    return redirect('core:checkout')
                else:
                    messages.error(self.request, "Coupon Does not Exists")
                    return redirect('core:checkout')

            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                messages.info(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
                return redirect('core:checkout')
```

Here is the forms.py

```
class CouponForm(forms.Form):
    code = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Promo code',
        'aria-label': "Recipient's username",
        'aria-describedby': "basic-addon2"
    }))
```

Comment: 10 times per user or per coupon? If you want 10 times over all you would have to add a counter to the Coupon model and increase the value each time by 1. When the coupon was used 10 times change the `active` field to `False`. 10 times per User: add a field to the User model and save which coupon was used....

Comment: @hansTheFranz How would I change the active field to False? I can add the counter in Model but how to adjust the status.

Comment: in this `if coupon_qs:` statment you can add `coupon_qs[0].counter +=1` and `coupon_qs[0].save()`. You could add another if statment here to set the `active` attr to False (`coupon_qs[0].active = False`) if the counter is over 10.